# show hide fields based on dropdown list items selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to show and hide columns in a table based on the selected item from a dropdown list.
Table has these columns:

- X
- Y
- Z

Dropdown list has these options:

- A
- B
- C

When A is selected i want to show all the fields (X,Y,Z) in the table but when B or C are selected i want to hide Y and show just X and Z. The table is displayed as a form filled out by the user. 
When I select B from the ddl and click save after that the form is saved without Y (that's what we need) but the issue is here, when I open again the saved form and I select A the column Y doesn't show, I'll have to select A then click save then open again the form to be able to see the column Y. For some reason The column Y doesn't show up immediately after choosing B from the dropdown list.

This is my code:

```
 <tr>
    <td align="right">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_1" runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">A</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="1">B</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="2">C</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>

 </tr>
```

JQ Function:

```
$(function () {

        $("#ddl_1").change(function () {
            if ($("#ddl_1").val() == 0) 
            {

                $("#Y").show(); 


            }

            else if (($("#ddl_1").val() == 1) || ($("#ddl_1").val() == 2))
            {


                $("#Y").hide(); 

            }

  })
});
```

How can I make the column Y shows up immediately after choosing B or C from the ddl without having to change the selection in ddl then save the form then open again the form to be able to see the column Y? Thank you

Comment: Do a View Source or an Inspect Element. I very much doubt that the ID of your rendered `<select>` is `ddl_1`. ASP.Net controls render on the page with automated ID's - you can get the *client ID* (the one jQuery wants) by doing `$("#<%=ddl_1.ClientID%>")` or by putting `ClientIdMode="Static"` on the `<asp:DropDownList>` to force the client ID to be `ddl_1`.

Comment: i tried it by doing $("#<%=ddl_1.ClientID%>") but it didn't work. I always have to choose from the ddl and click save then open the form again to be able to make the column Y showing up